# wso2 esb how to connect and query to HBASE

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In Wso2 ESB how to connect to HBase and query. As wso2 ESB we have dblookup mediator but it is for sql databases. So is there any solution for connection with HBASE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first provide the datasource details in wso2 esb, either you can do from front end or backend. i have mentioned the path `WSO2_Home/repository/conf/datasources/`update below in datasource.xml file.

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2_ANALYTICS_RS_DB_HBASE</name>
    <description>The datasource used for analytics file system</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2HBaseDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="HBASE">
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>localhost</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>2181</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>fs.file.impl</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

After the changes try restarting the server and see if you are able to connect from front end.

Comment: thank you for the reply, the configuration you have mentioned is to change ESB database as HBASE but I am asking about mediator(like dbllokup mediator) is there any to query HBASE.